# What is this crime, "F and A", from the 1890's US?

Tags: united-states, law, crime

What was the crime of "F and A" in North Carolina in the United States in the 1890's?

My wife saw that one of her female ancestors was arrested and served 6 months in jail for this crime in the 1890's, but we have not been able to find out what it is exactly.

Comment: Was the 'and' actually part of the text, or just F. A.? F.A. might be felonious assault

Comment: Can you post an image of the document containing this? More information at least such as the city and date might enable a newspaper search to find another source concerning the crime.

Comment: The term is used in one source to indicate "from & after" -.  time in custody, but not under sentence.  Might that be it?  Could she have been imprisoned in association with another charge? Or imprisoned but released without trial? Or some similar case?

Comment: Was the "and" written out?

Comment: Yes, the "and" was spelled out.  It was from the site digitalnc.org in the Danbury Reporter newspaper.  I'll try and find the story again so I can try to paste pic or link to it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The crime reported in the newspapers as "f. and a." was "Fornication and Adultery", as in this case from 1922:

[image: Fornication & Adultery]

The penalty handed down to Oakey Ferguson in this case of "one year on road" meant serving a year working in a NC road gang.

As I understand it, Fornication and Adultery remains an offence (actually a Class 2 misdemeanour) on the [statute books](http://law.justia.com/codes/north-carolina/2005/chapter_14/gs_14-184.html) in North Carolina.

[If you happen to live in North Carolina today, and you are thinking about dating before you are legally divorced, [basic legal advice](http://www.ncfamilylaw.com/download/date46.html) is available from a number of websites.]

Comment: so no sex outside of marriage in NC? Wonder how many residents of the state would go to prison if that were still enforced ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  We thought it was probably along these lines.  Just couldn't figure out the right words.

Comment: @Bradley - Have fun explaining that one to your mom!

Comment: @jwenting - Well, [Governor Mark Sanford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Sanford%27s_disappearance_and_extramarital_affair) for one.

Comment: How many politicians would still be in office :)